# XSSFSheet getLastRow() works but get the cells of lastrow return null

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2007

Test    Test    Test    Test    Test    Test
1        2       3        4      5       6
$cell   $cell   $cell   $cell   $cell   $cell

here's the code:

```
File file = new File("mytemplate.xlsx");
FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(file);

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(filein);
filein.close();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
int lastrow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
int phyrow = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

XSSFRow modlrow = sheet.createRow(lastrow);----still work, modlrow = 2
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(2));---still work
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2));  ---still work
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(lastrow).getCell(2)+"=========");don't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is these two lines:

```
XSSFRow modlrow = sheet.createRow(lastrow);----still work, modlrow = 2
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(lastrow).getCell(2)+"=========");don't work
```

The first one creates a brand new, empty row. The second tries to read from a specific cell in a row with no creation

You either need to explicitly create that cell, eg:

```
XSSFRow modlrow = sheet.createRow(lastrow);
modlrow.createCell(2);
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(lastrow).getCell(2)+"=========");
```

Or do your fetch with a [Missing Cell Policy](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html) to have the non-existant cell created for you on demand, eg:

```
XSSFRow modlrow = sheet.createRow(lastrow);
modlrow.createCell(2);
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(lastrow).getCell(2, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)+"=========");
```